# Why the compiler says that itemize doesn't end?

Tags: lists, itemize

I have this nested itemize in file `Chapters/Implementation`:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{resizeDim N} resize each processed image so the largest size is at most \texttt{N}. The user shoudl set it 0 he/she wish to use the original image size (default 0).
\item \texttt{DESCRIPTOR} define the used image descriptor (default \texttt{SIFTOpenCV 0 3 0.04 10 1.6}):
\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{PHA} (no options are needed)
\item \texttt{SIFTOpenCV nfeatures nOctaveLayers contrastThreshold edgeThreshold sigma} where the first argument is the keyword and the rest are the parameters described in OpenCV documentation about the SIFT descriptor.
\item \texttt{SURFOpenCv hessianThreshold nOctaves nOctaveLayers extended upright} where the first argument is the keyword and the rest are the parameters described in OpenCV documentation about the SURF descriptor.
\end{itemize}
\item \texttt{OMP v} enables parallel descriptor computation (as described in \ref{sect:trainingWorkflow}) if $v$ is set to 1 (default 1).
\item \texttt{ENCODER} is the used image encoder (default \texttt{VLAD  16 128  "NORMALIZE_COMPONENTS"):
\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{VLAD k descDim flag} where \texttt{k} is the number of descriptors, \texttt{descDim} is the size of the used descriptor and \texttt{flag} is used when the VLFeat implementation of this encoder is used (to use it instead of our implmenetation, set \texttt{LCS=-DVLFEAT} in the makefile). This parameter is useless (but mandatory) when using our implementation (set it to \texttt{VL\_VLAD\_FLAG\_SQUARE\_ROOT \textbar \- VL\_VLAD\_FLAG\_\-NORMALIZE\_COMPONENTS} in that case).
\item \texttt{FisherVector k descDim flag} same as above, but using dedicated FV \texttt{flag} described in VLFeat C documentation.
\item \texttt{nQueriesFraction N} use only \texttt{N}\% of the setup images to initialize the cache. This is used for evaluation in \ref{sect:setupSizeTest}.
\end{itemize}
\item \texttt{dataset DATSETNAME} decides which dataset to use. The three possible values for \texttt{DATASETNAME} are:
\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{oxford}
\item \texttt{painting}
\item \texttt{posters}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Which returns me this error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \texttt .<inserted text>\par \include{Chapters/Implementation}
! LaTeX Error: \begin{itemize} on input line 569 ended by \end{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{document}
```

But it looks fine to me (especially because I think that all the \begin{itemize}...\end{itemize} are correctly nested), where is the error?

If I delete this, the document is correctly generated.

Comment: The real error message is in the line before. The \texttt of `VLAD  16 128  "NORMALIZE_COMPONENTS"` is missing a closing brace.

Comment: For a tool to help you track these things down, see [a question of mine at superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/769353/grep-count-number-of-matches-per-line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line 11 `(default \texttt{VLAD  16 128  "NORMALIZE_COMPONENTS"):` the closing brace is missing. Maybe there are more …

**How to find such errors?**

Just comment out blocks of codes until the error disappears. You may start with bigger chunks of lines an the narrow it down to the line where the error occurs.

Comment: I looked for that little bastard for like 15 minutes

Comment: @user6321: See my edit on how to finde such nasty errors ;-) and you may also like to accept my answer :-D